# Confusing curly bracket issue with try catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I am just trying to use a try catch statement but for some reason it only works when I do the following:

```
{try {
    img = ImageIO.read(originalImageone);
    Image one= img.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    imgtwo = ImageIO.read(ogImagetwo);
    Image two = imgtwo.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    imgthree = ImageIO.read(Imagethree);
    Image three = imgthree.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    imgfour = ImageIO.read(Imagefour);
    Image four = imgfour.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    imgfive = ImageIO.read(Imagefive);
    Image five = imgfive.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    imgsix = ImageIO.read(Imagesix);
    Image six = imgsix.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    imgseven = ImageIO.read(Imageseven);
    Image seven = imgseven.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
    imgeight = ImageIO.read(Imageeight);
    Image eight = imgeight.getScaledInstance(512, 512, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

The statement above the beginning line of code is:

```
 BufferedImage imgeight = null;
```

So for some reason the above works despite the fact that there is an extra curly bracket as you can see. Every time I try to remove the extra curly brackets I get an error. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: The statement above the beginning line of code is:

Comment: Is this code inside a method or constructor?

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Why you cannot just provide a single code block that contains all lines of code relevant.... i.e why you keep the "BufferedImage ..." line above separated from the rest in your question?

Comment: "extra curly braket"... you mean an extra PAIR of curly brackets?

Comment: What is a type of error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You apparently accidentally found a use for an anonymous "static initialization" block.  try and catch are keywords that can only be found within "executable" code blocks like methods (and static blocks - where code runs before objects are constructed).  To make it explicit and clear try writing this:

```
BufferedImage img = null;
...
BufferedImage imgeight = null;
static {
    try {
          ...
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
          ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might be assuming too much.... although is possible what you are saying I don't think you can jump to that conclusion. The question (code) needs to be improve so that we understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: Can you point to another reason why try/catch would only "work" (not be flagged as compiler errors) when surrounded by an additional pair of braces?

Comment: Yet another example of what I'm talking about... nowhere in the question he actually says that is a **compilation** error .... he just says error. It could be runtime ... even just a warning but he call it an error ... who knows!

Comment: Also the use of **static** block is kinda of advance for a guy that has this kind of questions so I suspect that this is not the case... although he may be modifying someone elses code, that is true.

Comment: This pretty much worked I just put the entire code into a static method. Thanks for actually trying to help unlike everyone else who just downvotes new users that clearly don't know that they are doing.

Comment: I'm guessing you are/were trying to write all your code in one class with a static main() method, and you initially tried to put "the entire code" into a regular instance method of the class, but the compiler wouldn't let you call an instance method from inside the static main() method, and while trying to fix that issue you discovered the static initializer fix but didn't understand why it fixed your issue.  Going forward I recommend using at least two classes, one for just your static main() method and one for everything else, then make a new instance of EverythingElse() inside main().